# How to reference cells from another sheet

Tags: excel

I have two sheets, s1 and s2. I want to make calculations on the data in s1 and enter them in cells in s2.

If data in s1 is in column A from rows 1 - 10, I should be able to find the mean by typing =MEAN(s1!A1:A10), right? All the google searches I've done support this. But all that happens is that I see '=MEAN(s1!A1:A10)' typed in the cell in s2. Its like the function isn't applying.

Comment: Select the range where you want to enter the formula and then change it's Number Formatting from TEXT to GENERAL. Then reenter the formula.

Comment: Did that fix your problem?

Comment: Yes that worked, thanks!

Comment: Shall I make it an answer? Will you accept it?

Comment: Of course! Go ahead

Comment: OK. I just made the solution into an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

From your description of the problem it sounds like the Number Formatting is set to TEXT for the range where you are entering formulas that do not calculate, but instead just display as the entire formulas.

To fix this problem, the solution is to set the Number Formatting to GENERAL for the affected range and then to re-enter the formulas.

Comment: Did this answer your question satisfactorily?